# increasing ServerLimit & MaxClients on Apache

Tags: apache

This has happened to me in the past and I somehow fixed it now I cant remember...

After increasing MaxClients and ServerLimit and restarting apache, it still doesn't let new connections to come in...

```
KeepAlive Off
ServerLimit 1000
MinSpareServers 20
MaxSpareServers 50
StartServers 50
MaxClients 900
```

Comment: Does this belong on ServerFault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright found the issue :) for the reference, when you update MaxClient, RESTARTing apache is sufficient. But when updating ServerLimit, you have to actually STOP apache, then START! :)